# Loopback beforeRemote for PUT requests

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Using Loopback framework, I want to perform some operations before the `Item` is edited hence I am trying this but unable to bind this to the update hook.

```
  Item.beforeRemote("update", function(ctx,myitem,next) {
   console.log("inside update");
  });
```

Instead of update I have tried with **updateAttributes**,**updateById**, **create** but none works. This kind of beforeRemote hook works well with create on **POST**, but unable to get it with **PUT** during edit. 
The last solution left with me is again inspect the methodString with wildcard hook but I want to know if there is anything documented which I could not find.

```
Item.beforeRemote("**",function(ctx,instance,next){
  console.log("inside update");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried "*.save" as the method name?

Comment: *. save is an operation hook i am interested in remote hook

Answer (score 7):

I know that two year have passed since this post was opened, but if any body have the same question and if you use the endpoint `your_model/{id}` the afterRemote hook is `replaceById`.
If you need to know which method is fired in remote hook use this code:

```
yourModel.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, unused, next) {
    console.info('Method name: ', ctx.method.name);
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to the comments, `save` is a remote hook, not an operation hook, but you want to use it as: `prototype.save`. The relevant operational hook would be `before save`. You can see a table of these on the [LoopBack docs page](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-Hooks). I would probably implement this as an operational hook though, and use the `isNewInstance` property on the context to only perform the action on update:

```
Item.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
    // do something with ctx.currentInstance
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: I want to parse multipart using formidable, I use the loopback storage container's upload method for that through which I get the relevant fields. **These fields are unavailable in operation hooks**.Secondly save which you say is given in the documentation as remote hook is clearly mentioned that it is a custom remote hook means any method whose name ends with save, please read doc: **This remote hook is called whenever any remote method whose name ends with "save" is executed:[code]**

Comment: @SwapnilGondkar I appreciate your efforts to help clarify, but I work for StrongLooop, and I'm telling you that `save` is not an operation hook. There is `before save` and `after save`, but **not** `save` by itself. That is a "remote hook" on the prototype. Trust me, I helped write the docs. As for the fields not being available in the hook callback, that's not surprising. You might need to use a piece of middleware to add the fields to the request object so that they are available in the hook callback via the context.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for bumping into old question but its for those who are still searching.

'prototype.updateAttributes' can be used as remote hook for update requests.
and @jakerella , there is no remote hook called 'save' , i myself tried it, but didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Came here looking for another thing, guess it will be helpful to someone.
For before remote `model/:id` patch method you have to use "`prototype.patchAttributes`".

Comment: Thanks!, The [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#exposing-and-hiding-models-methods-and-endpoints) really bumped me up. `MyUser.disableRemoteMethodByName("prototype.updateAttributes");           // disables PATCH /MyUsers/{id}`

Answer (score 0):

On loopback3 for PATCH you can use "prototype.patchAttributes" to sanitize your data before the update.

```
YourModel.beforeRemote('prototype.patchAttributes', (ctx, unused, next) => { 
  console.log(ctx.args.data);
  next();
});
```